# Problemas al ejecutar fadeOut

Tags: javascript

En la siguiente función si cambio la clase `hidden` por un desvanecimiento, ya no funciona el resto del script, salvo si recargo la página.
Es decir, el elemento al que afecta el desvanecimiento ya no aparece al hacer `click` en el botón.

```
hide: function ()
{
  $(window).off('keydown', null, null, this._onKeydown.bind(this));
    this.$dtpElement.addClass('hidden');
    this.$element.trigger('close');
},
```

Comment: puedes poner mas código para ayudarte

Comment: Es que es así! Esto pasa porque seguro esta usando fade para que desaparezca pero no para que vuelva a aparecer. Debes usar fadeOut() para que desaparezca y luego al hacer click en el botón debes llamar a un fadeIn() para que reaparezca el elemento.

Answer (score -1):

En vista que no suministras el código completo he elaborado un ejemplo que funciona perfectamente para que observes donde esta tu error. El ejemplo contiene dos botones y un div. Un botón al hacer click hace que desaparezca el div y el otro botón al presionarlo hace que reaparezca nuevamente.

Esto lo he logrado con las funciones de Jquery fadeIn y fadeOut. Quizás el error que tu estas teniendo es que estás utilizando una sola de ellas (desapareces el elemento más cuando haces click nuevamente no capturas el evento para hacer que reaparezca nuevamente)

He aquí el ejemplo:

```js
$("#fadein").click(function(){
$("#caja").fadeIn("slow");
});

$("#fadeout").click(function(){
$("#caja").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="fadein" id="fadein" value="aparece">

<input type="submit" name="fadeout" id="fadeout" value="desaparece">


<div id="caja" style="background-color:#ff0000; width:50%; margin-top:20%;"> Elemento que aparece y 
desaparece
</div>
```

También tienes una función que fusiona tanto fadeIn como fadeOut y se llama fadeToggle por lo que solo necesitas presionar un botón para que desaparezca y luego presionar el mismo botón nuevamente para que aparezca. Que funciona como te muestro acontinuación:

```js
$("#fadein").click(function(){
$("#caja").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="fadein" id="fadein" value="unico">


<div id="caja" style="background-color:#ff0000; width:50%; margin-top:20%;"> Elemento que aparece y 
desaparece
</div>
```

Para efectos de tu código sólo cambia:

```
this.$dtpElement.addClass('hidden');
```

por el evento fade así:

```
this.$dtpElement.fadeToggle("slow");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Se puede saber porque el negativo? La respuesta esta bien y además el código funciona.

Comment: No. Al contrario. Muchas gracias por la pista. Me sirvió.  Lo solucioné simple añadiendo la función fadeIn al unir.